# Google App Engine vs Pagoda Box?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, web-hosting, paas, pagoda-box

Particularly, for PHP development, which one performs better? I'd like to deploy a Zend Framework 1.X app on the chosen platform. Which one makes this easier/possible?

Comment: **1)** "I know this post is a great candidate for getting closed as not constructive" - **Then why did you ask it?** **2)** "but I find that some of the best questions I run into here at StackOverflow are of this kind (...)" That's because many of those questions are **old**. The standards have changed over the past years.

Comment: A good question is still a good question after a few years... That's why I asked the question - because the answer to a good question is often worthwhile.

Comment: Not according to today's standards of StackOverflow, they are not. The problem is just that because there are so many of them, it's hard to close the old questions that should be closed according to today's standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I particularly love about Pagodabox is how they "force" you to use git (or some other version control system). I know you probably wouldn't use either GAE of PB for trivial projects, so you're probably already using some version control system. But I still think that's a nice touch of them. Plus it makes deploying that much easier.

Comment: You can deploy direct from git with appengine too.  But it doesn't force you too.  Which is a good thing, especially if you use hg and not git ;-)